# Flex child not overflowing(Its Collapsing)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjEpbj) I am trying to fill the height of parent if child height is less than the parent or overflow the children if their height exceeds that of the parent.
But when I hardcode child height, I expect a scrollbar. But instead, the children are just filling the parent.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.grand-parent{
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  display:flex;
}
.parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  min-height:100%;
  width:300px;
}

.child{
  height:1500px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}

.green{
  background:green;
}

.blue{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child green"></div>
    <div class="child blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grand-parent{
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

.parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  min-height: 100%;
  background:red;
}

.child{
  height:150px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}

.green{
  background:green;
}

.blue{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child green"></div>
   <div class="child blue"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The mistake you did was, you added `display: flex` to `.grand-parent` and `flex: 1` to the `.parent`. That means the `.parent` will adjust according to the height of `.grand-parent`. So I have removed that 2 properties from the style

Comment: what if the child height is less and I want it to fill the screen? I did try ur approach before posting.

Comment: You can give `min-height: 100%`  to `.parent`. Please let me know if there is anything else

Comment: I have updated the code, it seems the child content is collapsing if I remove `flex:1`.

Comment: any idea why the parent height is 0.

Comment: I have updated the code as well. Check now. Currently, I have given the red color to the `.parent` and given `150px` height to each child. Increase the height and verify yourself

Answer (score 0):

Don't use flex for the `parent`, instead set `min-height: 50%` for the `child`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.grand-parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.parent {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 50%;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child green"></div>
    <div class="child blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```